# C# reference clarification

Tags: c#

A few days back I came into an interesting thing, but I can't wrap my head around it, or let's say I have a feeling what is happening, but I'm not sure.

Having the following linked list implementation:

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        public T Value;
        public Node? Next;
        public Node(T value) => (Next, Value) = (null, value);
    }

    private Node? head;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
    }
    public void InsertBack1(T value)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(value);
        }
        else
        {
            Node? current = head;
            while (current?.Next != null)
            {
                current = current.Next;
            }
            current.Next = new Node(value); ;
        }
    }

    public void InsertBack2(T value)
    {
        Node? current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }
        current = new Node(value);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        var current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.Write(current.Value + " --> ");
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

By using the `InsertBack1()` method, the insertion works just fine, however the `InsertBack2()` method does not.
Using the following snippet:

```
var list = new LinkedList<int>();
list.InsertBack1(1);
list.InsertBack1(2);
list.InsertBack2(3);
```

I get the following linked list: 1 -> 2.

In the `InsertBack2()` method, the code checks whether the current node is *null* or not, if it's not, moves the *current* reference to the child or creates a new node for the corresponding element. In theory it should be fine, but while running the new node is not inserted. As I understand, when the *current* is moved to an uninitialized child, it somehow looses all reference from the *head* object and goes out of sync (let's say so).

In the `InsertBack1()` method however it just works, the *current* object gets a new child and the *head* object receives the modifications as well.

So what is happening here exactly with the references?

Comment: `current` is a local variable, it's never added to the list

Comment: Classic NullReferenceException here. Look at this line in _InsertBack2_ `while (current != null)`, so when you exit the loop what is the "value" of _current_?

Comment: @Steve For a change, there's no NRE here, because current is only assigned to after the loop. However, the result of that assignment is never used.

Comment: @PMF _current.Next = new Node(value);_ gives a NRE if current is null.

Comment: @Steve But that is not part of `InsertBack2`, where the OP has the problem. Also, the Problem is not an NRE here, but that the operation just does nothing.

Comment: Pretty sure that I copied and tested the code with current.Next. Probably there is some ghost around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what happens when you call `InsertBack2(3)`.

```
public void InsertBack2(T value)
    {
        Node? current = head; // current now points to node 1
        while (current != null)
        {
            // current is not null, so try next
            current = current.Next;
        }
        // The above loop will execute two times, after which current points to  null (which is the termination criteria for the loop)
        current = new Node(value); // Now current is null and we assign a new instance. 
    }
```

See my comments above. After the last line, current contains the new node, but since it's a local variable, it just runs out of scope and is forgotten. That node is never added to the list. A similar implementation would work, if the method `InsertBack3()` would be a method of `Node`, but that gets a quite different data structure.